# Not able to save child table data using hibernate

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, rest

I am Developing Web service, in this there is scenario of parent child tables as below

```
**Parent Table**
@Entity
@Table(name = "INSTITUTE_LIST_MST")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class InstituteInfoMatster
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "LIST_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer listId;

    @Column(name = "LIST_DESC")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "LIST_VALUE")
    private String value;

    @Column(name = "URL")
    private String url;

    @Column(name = "LOGO", unique = false, length = 100000)
    private byte[] logo;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "instituteInfotMaster", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<InstituteInfoDetails> instituteInfoDetails = new ArrayList<InstituteInfoDetails>();

    @Column(name = "CREATED_DT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate = new Date();

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_DT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedDate;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_BY")
    private String updatedBy;

    @Column(name = "RECORD_STATUS")
    private String recordStatus = "A";

    public Integer getListId()
    {
        return listId;
    }

    public void setListId(Integer listId)
    {
        this.listId = listId;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate()
    {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate)
    {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy()
    {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy)
    {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedDate()
    {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate()
    {
        this.updatedDate = new Date();
    }

    public String getUpdatedBy()
    {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy)
    {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    public String getRecordStatus()
    {
        return recordStatus;
    }

    public void setActiveRecordStatus()
    {
        this.recordStatus = "A";
    }

    public void deleteRecord()
    {
        this.recordStatus = "D";
    }

    public List<InstituteInfoDetails> getInstituteInfoDetails()
    {
        return instituteInfoDetails;
    }

    public void setInstituteInfoDetails(List<InstituteInfoDetails> instituteInfoDetails)
    {
        this.instituteInfoDetails = instituteInfoDetails;
    }

    public byte[] getLogo()
    {
        return logo;
    }

    public void setLogo(byte[] logo)
    {
        this.logo = logo;
    }

    public String getUrl()
    {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "InstituteInfoMatster [listId=" + listId + ", description=" + description + ", value=" + value + ", url="
                + url + ", logo=" + Arrays.toString(logo) + ", instituteInfoDetails=" + instituteInfoDetails
                + ", createdDate=" + createdDate + ", createdBy=" + createdBy + ", updatedDate=" + updatedDate
                + ", updatedBy=" + updatedBy + ", recordStatus=" + recordStatus + "]";
    }

}
```

**Child Table**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INSTITUTE_LIST_DETAILS")
public class InstituteInfoDetails
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "LIST_DTL_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer listDtlId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "LIST_ID", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty("instituteInfotMaster")
    @JsonBackReference
    private InstituteInfoMatster instituteInfotMaster;

    @Column(name = "LIST_DTL_VALUE")
    private String value;

    @Column(name = "LIST_DTL_DESC", length = 5000)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "STRING1", length = 5000)
    private String string1;

    @Column(name = "STRING2", length = 5000)
    private String string2;

    @Column(name = "STRING3", length = 5000)
    private String string3;

    @Column(name = "SEQUENCE_NO")
    private int sequenceNo;

    @Column(name = "NUMBER1")
    private Double number1;

    @Column(name = "NUMBER2")
    private Double number2;

    @Column(name = "NUMBER3")
    private Double number3;

    @Column(name = "DOCUMENT", unique = false, length = 100000)
    private byte[] document;

    @Column(name = "DOCUMENT_TYPE", length = 1)
    private Integer documentType;

    @Column(name = "DOCUMENT1", unique = false, length = 100000)
    private byte[] document1;

    @Column(name = "DOCUMENT1_TYPE", length = 1)
    private Integer document1Type;

    @Column(name = "DOCUMENT2", unique = false, length = 100000)
    private byte[] document2;

    @Column(name = "DOCUMENT2_TYPE", length = 1)
    private Integer document2Type;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_DT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate = new Date();

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_DT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedDate;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_BY")
    private String updatedBy;

    @Column(name = "RECORD_STATUS")
    private String recordStatus = "A";

    public Integer getListDtlId()
    {
        return listDtlId;
    }

    public void setListDtlId(Integer listDtlId)
    {
        this.listDtlId = listDtlId;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public InstituteInfoMatster getComListMaster()
    {
        return instituteInfotMaster;
    }

    public void setComListMaster(InstituteInfoMatster instituteInfotMaster)
    {
        this.instituteInfotMaster = instituteInfotMaster;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate()
    {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate()
    {
        this.createdDate = new Date();
    }

    public String getCreatedBy()
    {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy)
    {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedDate()
    {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate)
    {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }

    public String getUpdatedBy()
    {
        return updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy)
    {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    public String getRecordStatus()
    {
        return recordStatus;
    }

    public void setRecordStatus(String recordStatus)
    {
        this.recordStatus = recordStatus;
    }

    public InstituteInfoMatster getInstituteInfotMaster()
    {
        return instituteInfotMaster;
    }

    public void setInstituteInfotMaster(InstituteInfoMatster instituteInfotMaster)
    {
        this.instituteInfotMaster = instituteInfotMaster;
    }

    public String getString1()
    {
        return string1;
    }

    public void setString1(String string1)
    {
        this.string1 = string1;
    }

    public String getString2()
    {
        return string2;
    }

    public void setString2(String string2)
    {
        this.string2 = string2;
    }

    public String getString3()
    {
        return string3;
    }

    public void setString3(String string3)
    {
        this.string3 = string3;
    }

    public int getSequenceNo()
    {
        return sequenceNo;
    }

    public void setSequenceNo(int sequenceNo)
    {
        this.sequenceNo = sequenceNo;
    }

    public Double getNumber1()
    {
        return number1;
    }

    public void setNumber1(Double number1)
    {
        this.number1 = number1;
    }

    public Double getNumber2()
    {
        return number2;
    }

    public void setNumber2(Double number2)
    {
        this.number2 = number2;
    }

    public Double getNumber3()
    {
        return number3;
    }

    public void setNumber3(Double number3)
    {
        this.number3 = number3;
    }

    public byte[] getDocument()
    {
        return document;
    }

    public void setDocument(byte[] document)
    {
        this.document = document;
    }

    public Integer getDocumentType()
    {
        return documentType;
    }

    public void setDocumentType(Integer documentType)
    {
        this.documentType = documentType;
    }

    public byte[] getDocument1()
    {
        return document1;
    }

    public void setDocument1(byte[] document1)
    {
        this.document1 = document1;
    }

    public Integer getDocument1Type()
    {
        return document1Type;
    }

    public void setDocument1Type(Integer document1Type)
    {
        this.document1Type = document1Type;
    }

    public byte[] getDocument2()
    {
        return document2;
    }

    public void setDocument2(byte[] document2)
    {
        this.document2 = document2;
    }

    public Integer getDocument2Type()
    {
        return document2Type;
    }

    public void setDocument2Type(Integer document2Type)
    {
        this.document2Type = document2Type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "InstituteInfoDetails [listDtlId=" + listDtlId + ", instituteInfotMaster=" + instituteInfotMaster
                + ", value=" + value + ", description=" + description + ", string1=" + string1 + ", string2=" + string2
                + ", string3=" + string3 + ", sequenceNo=" + sequenceNo + ", number1=" + number1 + ", number2="
                + number2 + ", number3=" + number3 + ", document=" + Arrays.toString(document) + ", documentType="
                + documentType + ", document1=" + Arrays.toString(document1) + ", document1Type=" + document1Type
                + ", document2=" + Arrays.toString(document2) + ", document2Type=" + document2Type + ", createdDate="
                + createdDate + ", createdBy=" + createdBy + ", updatedDate=" + updatedDate + ", updatedBy=" + updatedBy
                + ", recordStatus=" + recordStatus + "]";
    }

}
```

now i am using below rest service request to add master data with child

```
{"description":"Placements","value":"Placements","url":"/Placements","instituteInfoDetails":[{"value":"Test"}]}
```

**Code to save data**

```
@Override
    public void addInstituteInfoMaster(com.zertones.model.common.InstituteInfoMatster instituteInfoMatster)
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(instituteInfoMatster);

    }
```

but while saving it gives me below error

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.zertones.model.common.InstituteInfoDetails.instituteInfotMaster
```

I searched and did as per solutions i added the cascade type information, but it did not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create bidirectional Setter method for set InstituteInfoMatster to instituteInfoDetails

change class InstituteInfoMatster

```
public void setInstituteInfoDetails(List<InstituteInfoDetails> instituteInfoDetails)
{
    for(InstituteInfoDetails ins : instituteInfoDetails){
        ins.setComListMaster(this);
    }
    this.instituteInfoDetails = instituteInfoDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo in this code:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "LIST_ID", nullable = false)
@JsonProperty("instituteInfotMaster")
@JsonBackReference
private InstituteInfoMatster instituteInfotMaster;
```

Shouldn't it be `instituteInfoMaster` instead?

EDIT: or maybe not, I can se you have multiple typos there, such as `InstituteInfoMatster` etc. Still, I think it would worth to fix these typos while you still can (if you still can, of course).